# JQuery simple example to save edited content

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a simple example to save content from a contentEditable div without using php. I can't use php because I am using it in Google Docs. I would prefer an example with innerHTML.

Comment: and i am looking for a piece of `code`, in your `POST`

Comment: It depends what you are trying to save it to, as to whether this is possible or not.  You need to do a bit more research, give it a go and then come back with a more specific question as in its current format, your question is way to broad and not [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for his site

Comment: Some people seem to actually understand what I mean though :) `here is your code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `PHP` or any `Server Side Script` then you can use only [cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) like

```
$('div.contentEditable').on('keyup',function(){
    localStorage.setItem('content',$(this).html());
});
```

And get the localstorage item like,

```
localStorage.getItem('content');// if content is previously set
```

And if you can use Server side script then use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) to store it in database and use it.